# How can i print selected Items on save print to console

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with some Angular code. It is an infragistics multi-select box and it has a save bttn which calls a function to update the Array with the keys. For some reason it always sends all the values in the multi-select box instead of only the selected ones.

Here is my component code

```
    _contactId: string;
    @Input() set contactId(contactId: string) {
        this._contactId = contactId;
    };
    get contactId() {
        return this._contactId;
    }

    _allBuckets: IServerDropdownOption[];
    @Input() set allBuckets(allBuckets: IServerDropdownOption[]) {
        this._allBuckets = [...allBuckets];
    };
    get allBuckets() {
        return this._allBuckets;
    }

    _selectedBuckets: Array<string>;
    @Input() set selectedBuckets(selectedBuckets: Array<string>) {
        this._selectedBuckets = selectedBuckets;
    };
    get selectedBuckets() {
        return this._selectedBuckets;
    }

    @ViewChild('chipsSelect', { read: ChipsSelectComponent })
    public chipsSelect: ChipsSelectComponent;

    alive = true;

  constructor(private contactsService: ContactsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.chipsSelect.multiSelectBox.onSave
          .pipe(
              takeWhile(_ => this.alive),
              switchMap(updatedSelection => this.contactsService.updateBuckets(this.contactId, updatedSelection.map(tag => tag.value)))
            )
          .subscribe();
          console.log('Selected Buckets: ' + this.selectedBuckets)
  }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.alive = false;
    }
}
```

So i have 2 questions, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong to get all the selected ones saved and also how can i print all selected Items to console ones user clicks save. My current console.log prints only ones on init but not on save.

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Comment: The html will not do much good as it is a component  so then i would need to post the html and type script code of that as well and it would be to complicated. What would help me a lot to see what the this.selectedBuckets is when user clicks onSave. In the current position it shows me whats selected on load but not when save is hit since the ngAfterViewInit() only gets called once when form loads